# adding children to multidimensional array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array  having a tree like structure parent => child. I want to add children to the last array nodes  but I cannot figure out how. Below I have my array and the piece of code I have so far,i'm just stuck

```
  Array
    (
        [id] => 154
        [text] => root
        [parent_id] => 
        [children] => Array
            (
                [155] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 155
                        [text] => DE
                        [parent_id] => 154
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [157] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 157
                                        [text] => MÃ¼lheim
                                        [parent_id] => 155
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )        
                                    )

                                [158] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 158
                                        [text] => HeiÃŸen
                                        [parent_id] => 155
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )        
                                    )

                                [159] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 159
                                        [text] => Essen
                                        [parent_id] => 155
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )        
                                    )        
                            )        
                    )

                [156] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 156
                        [text] => RO
                        [parent_id] => 154
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [160] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 160
                                        [text] => Alba Iulia
                                        [parent_id] => 156
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )        
                                    )

                                [161] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 161
                                        [text] => Sibiu
                                        [parent_id] => 156
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )        
                                    )        
                            )        
                    )        
            )        
    )
```

Here is my recursive traverse function. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
function traverseArray($array, &$in_arr = array())
{
    foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    {
        if($k == 'children' && empty($v)){
             // here i am querying children data for the end node that has ['children'] => array(). 
             // I did some tests and it seems that no matter what i do here does not affect the $in_array variable at all

            $data = Location::all(array('conditions'=>array("parent_id=?", $array['id'])));

             // here I try to assign the new childrens to $in_array
            foreach ($data as $k=>$v){
                $in_arr['children'] = array('href'=>$v->id,'text'=>$v->name); 
            }
        }
        else{
            $in_arr[] = $v;
        }
        if(is_array($v))
        {
            traverseArray($v);
        }
    }
    return $in_arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the array to get the bottom level object and then go up one from there and add an element to that array.

```
$previousNode = null;
$node = //Top Level Object
while(sizeof($node->$children) > 0)
{
     $prevNode = $node;
     $node = $children[0];
}

//Switch to up one level
$node = previousNode;

//Add children like 
array_push($node->$children, //element);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Add array into structure with some child id.
 * @param int $child_id Child id
 * @param array $structure Initial structure.
 * @param array $add Add child array.
 */
function add_to_node($child_id, & $structure, $add) {
    foreach( $structure as & $data ) {
        if( isset($data['id']) ) {
            if( $data['id'] == $child_id ) {
                $data['children'][ $add['id'] ] = $add;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( isset($data['children']) ) {
            add_to_node($child_id, $data['children'], $add);
        }
    }
}

// Initial array structure.
$data = array(
    1 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'children' => array(
            12 => array(
                'id' => 12,
                'children' => array(),
            ),

            15 => array(
                'id' => 15,
                'children' => array(
                    55 => array(
                        'id' => 55,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

// This code will add new child with ID 44 to parent with id 55.
add_to_node(55, $data, array(
    'id' => 44,
    'text' => 'my text',
));

print_r($data);
```